# Copy and paste data from multiple workbooks last row to a worksheet in another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The code I've tweaked from another similar post, copies Row 3 to the last row which contains data from 'Sheet1' from all the workbooks in a folder into the 'SH Dealing yyyy.xlsx' 'DealSlips' sheet (adding to the rows here as it sweeps down through the workbooks in the folder). However, it only copies the last row which has data in Column A. In the last row there may be data just in Column J or Column Z for example and it doesn't see these and they are not copied? I'm new to coding and have been pretty much guessing for a couple of hours what needs changing in the code!

```
    Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Z:\2016\Deal slips ordered mmddyy\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("Z:\2016\Report\SH Dealing yyyy.xlsx")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("DealSlips")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Copy data on "Sheet1" sheet to "DealSlips" Sheet in other workbook
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
       lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       ' lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       .Range("A3:Z" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End With

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result by changing the following line:

`lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

With:

`lRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Your original code will count the number of rows on a specific column, in your case Column A, whereas the one using `UsedRange` will look at the last row on your Sheet including cells that contain formatting only.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to find the last row without counting the cells with formatting would be as below:

```
Dim lRow As Long, lRow2 As Long
lRow = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row

 wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:Z" & lRow).Copy

 lRow2 = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=ws2.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
 ws2.Range("A" & lRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After looking at your code a little close I realized that  the lRow2 was throwing an error because the Sheet was actually blank, so I've added a line of code to add a "Header" to cell A1, so that it can calculate the last row appropriately, also I don't understand how you get the "Correct" result manually when I did it I got many more rows than you, but please check the code below, it worked for me (I think), I also moved the workbook with code (i.e. Book1.xlsm) outside the folder you are looping through and added an If statement to exclude the "SH Dealing yyyy.xlsx" workbook from the loop :

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
Dim wb As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim myPath As String, myFile As String, myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Z:\2016\Deal slips ordered mmddyy\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("Z:\2016\Report\SH Dealing yyyy.xlsx")
'amen
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("DealSlips")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    If Left(myFile, 2) <> "SH" Then
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Copy data on "Sheet1" sheet to "DealSlips" Sheet in other workbook
    lRow = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row ' + 1
            y.Sheets("DealSlips").Range("A1").Value = "Header"
    lRow2 = y.Sheets("DealSlips").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=y.Sheets("DealSlips").Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
            wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:Z" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & lRow2)

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Else
        myFile = ""
    End If
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply! However that's not doing it. I've just read somewhere that UsedRange might be affected by formatting? After each of the last rows with the required data there are rows underneath with formatting for the next 100 or so rows (each row has alternate blue then white highlighting and also column borders all the way down to the end of each sheet). However, the 'blank' rows with formatting are not been copied. Thanks

Comment: News just in. Further tests show UsedRange does work to a point, however the paste from the next Workbook in the folder from its 'Sheet1' will overwrite those rows if there are just entries in the J or Z column. Whereas if column A is populated, the next paste is put beneath. How do I get the macro to paste on the next row which has no data in it?

Comment: @MikeH what do you mean when you say his solution “isn’t doing it”?

Comment: @MikeH Please see my updated answer, I believe this should now work for you as you expect it to, could you also please mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the updated code Xabier but still the same result. It is still overwriting. I'll try to explain. Imagine if there were just 3 workbooks to be copied, each with data in A3:Z3 and J4:Z4. After the macro runs (It leaves the first row empty in the destination workbook but I'm not worried about that) I end up with data in in Cells A2:Z2, A3:Z3, A4:Z4 and J5:Z5, when what I want is data in A2:Z2, J3:Z3, A4:Z4, J5:Z5, A6:Z6, J7:Z7. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @MikeH I've now updated my answer once more, I'm not 100% sure this is what you need as I didn't really understand your explanation, but please do try my updated answer and see if it works as expected? :)

Comment: Hi. Gives a Run time error 91 and debug on the second block of text.

Comment: @MikeH try now, I think that was because we didn't declare the new variable... Plus I removed the With and End With statements from the code.

Comment: Error on 'second block of code' that should have been. Not sure how to else to explain it. Basically, if there's nothing in Column A from the previous paste (while there is data in other columns), this row(s) will get overwritten with the paste from next workbook.

Comment: @MIkeH, I updated my answer with a Dim for the variables, that should have fixed the Error 91, if you are still having issues, could you upload your spreadsheet to something like Google Drive and add a link in the comments here, so I can have a closer look at it?

Comment: Still Run Time error 91. At this point, it is now just opening the first workbook from the folder and copying (the source workbook stays open) but not pasting into the destination workbook.

Comment: @MikeH at this point I don't know how to further "guess" what is happening, if you could share your workbook I will indeed have a closer look at it and suggest a solution, without that, I've got nothing further to suggest.

Comment: Hi Xabier. Dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/99hmydya4g1yyin/AABCJFNRMWXRGN5XYWcVBCUoa?dl=0

Comment: In SHDealing yyyy.xlsx, 'DealSlips' sheet shows the incorrect result and the 'Correct' sheet  shows, well the correct result (manually done). Rows 29 to 30 of the Correct sheet have been overwritten in the DealSlips sheet. The macro I run from the separate workbook Book1 which needs to be pointed to the correct path of the source sheets (Dealing..). Ignore any cell formatting.

Comment: @MikeH I believe it works as expected now, even though I got a different number of rows than in your "Correct" sheet. Please try this now, hopefully it will get you further towards your goal. :)

Comment: Apologies, I had to move the files out of the server environment and I manually did both (I thought two workbooks with the 'full rows' all the way down were the same) so there should have been more rows in the results as you say but the principle remains the same. I can't see why this should now be happening, but It's now throwing an error on the Set y = Workbooks.Open("SH Dealing yyyy.xlsx") line?

Comment: @MikeH did you make sure that the path to the file is accurate?

Comment: Path was ok. I saw a message saying that the code had been updated and copied that over; however, I needed to first refresh the web page and it now works perfectly. Thank you so much. I've hit the feedback +ve arrow. Really appreciated. Mike

Comment: @MikeH, glad it worked in the end :) Please could you also mark my response as an accepted answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the greyed out tick. I've ticked that now. Thanks again for your time, patience and expertise. Very impressed - even helping a newbie like me.